# word2vec : Parameterization of the skip-gram model

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec

I am reading this paper [word2vec Explained](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3722v1.pdf) and came across equation (3). I dont exactly understand what is Vc and Vw. It says they are vector representation of words. But still what is it? How to get its value? I am about to implement it and want to know what exactly it means.

**Edit**: Are Vc and Vw one-hot vector of words as mentioned in [word2vec Parameter Learning Explained](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~ronxin/pdf/w2vexp.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Vc and Vw are the learned embeddings (vectors) for context and subject words respectively. These values are initially random - however the learning algorithm is iterative and will modify these values, eventually converging on good representations to satisfy the formula stated in (3).

In answer to your edit, these are not one-hot vectors, but instead are of size d (dimensions).

Comment: This being a very crucial part, sir can you please provide me an example that shows updation of Vc and Vw. I am still not clear. @John Wakefield

Comment: " word2vec Parameter Learning Explained" says that words are one hot encoded

Comment: Please see the original C code published by Tomas Mikolov which is here: http://word2vec.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/word2vec.c - line 479 updates word vectors for continuous bag of words and line 529 for skip gram. The same array of vectors {syn0} is used for both Vc and Vw - it's just the context that switches. The "one hot" index is used to point to the right value in syn0.

Comment: okay, but how are these vectors plotted in XY plane. I mean output of neural network is just maximum likelihood of a particular word. How these things are plotted which gives awesome results? @John Wakefield

Comment: Ah, I see - If you want a 2D visualisation of the high dimensional vectors, you could use something like t-SNE to generate a 2D scatterplot. This will attempt to preserve the spatial distance whist dropping away dimensions. See https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/

Comment: sorry I am beginner in ML. Now I got your 1st comment. We are converting high dimensional vectors using t-SNE to plot in 2D. Now which are these high dimensional vectors? Are they Vc and Vw? or the output that we are getting by equation (3)? @John Wakefield

Comment: If you check the Tomas Mikolov code above, you will see that Vc and Vw are both stored in the array syn0. This is what is saved to the output file. It's also what you would use to feed t-SNE. If you were to read the value for a word in syn0 it would be the same whether you used it for Vc or Vw. In the context of equation (3), Vc is a context word and Vw is the subject word. If Vc represented "dog" and Vw represented "dog", these values would be identical. The best way to understand this is play with the code.